# How to create an oracle hierarchical query that transforms sparse data to dense data

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

Say you have a tree of data

```
A
|
+----B
|    |
|    +----C
|
+----D
```

to represent this in an oracle database we might have

```
create table mydata (id number(10), parent_id number(10), name varchar2(10))
```

and use a hierarchical query to traverse the tree.

What is the best way to define a **sparse** property set, such that child nodes inherit property values from the closest parent node?

In the above example, say we want to add owner and colour to the tree - how can the hierarchical query be modified to provide the inherited values?

My first thought was to create a new table

```
create table myproperties (id number(10), owner varchar2(30), colour varchar2(30));
```

We'd want the values in this table to be sparse as well - so a row in myproperties might specify 'owner' but leave 'colour' null. A given node in mydata would have a merged set of all non-null parent properties.

Then do an analytic query to fill in the gaps:

```
select * from (
    select
        id, groupid, parent_id, 
        last_value(owner ignore nulls) over (partition by groupid order by l desc) owner,
        last_value(colour ignore nulls) over (partition by groupid order by l desc) colour
    from
        (
            -- query from leaf to root
            select
                id, connect_by_root id groupid, level l, p.owner, p.colour
            from
                mydata d left outer join myproperties p on p.id=d.id
            start with
                id in (select id from mydata)
            connect by prior
                parent_id=id
        )
)
where
    id=groupid -- filter out redundant rows required by the analytic function
```

Is this a reasonable way to achieve the goal of a dense view on sparse hierarchical properties, or is there a better way (more efficient, more comprehensible)?

Comment: I was thinking about using something along the lines of `SELECT level, id, perent_id, NVL(color, prior color)` and realized it would not work. :)

Comment: hi - yeah me too :) only good so long as you have data every other row

Comment: if this is not something performance critical, you could write a recursive function that would return the inherited value, and use it like `NVL(color, Get_Inherited_Color(parent_id)`. With `PRAGMA RESTRICT_REFERENCES(WNDS, WNPS, RNPS)` oracle will probably cache the values for you (I'm not sure though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to use a recursive `WITH` clause to build the hierarchy and use `DENSE_RANK` to determine the relevant properties:

```
WITH mydata AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id,NULL AS parent_id,'A' AS name FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'B' FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,'C' FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 4,1,'D' FROM DUAL),
myproperties AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id,'me' AS owner, 'red' AS colour FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 2,'you','blue' FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 3,'all',NULL FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 4,NULL,'green' FROM DUAL),
myhierarchy (id,ancestor,depth) AS --recursive
  (SELECT d.id,d.id,0 FROM mydata d
   UNION ALL SELECT d.id,h.id,h.depth+1
               FROM myhierarchy h
                 INNER JOIN mydata d ON d.parent_id = h.id)
SELECT h.id
      ,MAX(p.owner) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY NVL2(p.owner,1,2),h.depth) owner
      ,MAX(p.colour) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY NVL2(p.colour,1,2),h.depth) colour
  FROM myhierarchy h
    INNER JOIN myproperties p ON p.id=h.ancestor
  GROUP BY h.id;
```

Update: I added `NVL2(*,1,2)` in the `ORDER BY` clause of `DENSE_RANK` to have NULL values at the end. So NULL values will not overwrite the properties values.

Comment: Hiya this is very cool. However I think I wasn't exact enough in my specifications, though - your answer requires that each row in myproperties specifies _every_ property value - is this correct?
Ideally a property row could specify _some_ of the values. I'll modify my question to better indicate this.

Comment: I added `NVL2(*,1,2)` in the `ORDER BY` clause of `DENSE_RANK` to have NULL values at the end. So NULL values will not overwrite the properties values.